# Passing pickle strings between C# and IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, pickle

I wrote an IronPython package to do some data-crunching, and now I am wrapping it in a C# application. Part of the application's functionality is to save the state of a project, and then later to restore that saved state.

I am using the `pickle` module in IronPython to save an object of a class from my custom package. Before I did the wrapping in C#, that was no problem: I used the `pickle.dump()` function to serialize the object to a file. Now I want to use the `pickle.dumps()` function to serialize the object to a string, then pass that string to a C# object and serialize **THAT** object with an `XmlSerializer`.

Serialization seems to work, but deserialization breaks down: C# gets the deserialized string and passes it to IronPython, which should be able to reconstitute the original object with the `pickle.loads()` function, but instead raises this error:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException {"ô"}
```

Can you help me solve this problem? I have two theories:

1. Perhaps there is a difference in the string encodings between IronPython and C#, or between C#, IronPython, and what is expected by the `pickle` module?
2. Not the entire string is being serialized in the first place, so I am just passing nonsense to `pickle.loads()`

My evidence that leads me to these theories:

1. The missing key in the error message (ô) looks like a bit of unicode-parsed-as-ASCII-text.
2. If I break execution (in debug mode of Visual Studio 2010) and look at the string before it is passed to IronPython for unpicking, what I see is not long enough to represent the entire object. But it might just reach the limit of what the Visual Studio debugger will display.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hmmmm: <http://bugs.python.org/issue2980>

Comment: Could post some short code that exhibits this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid that the amount of code necessary to produce my setup goes beyond what would be reasonable here.

Comment: We don't need exactly your setup. But some (relatively) simple code that shows the same problem could help.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: pickling with `protocol=-1` works for me where the default, human-readable protocol does not.

Long answer: It looks like theory #1 is substantially correct. I use a dictionary of large numpy arrays to store my data, and even using the default "human-readable" pickling protocol, they are pickled to a binary-like form. Notice the fourth line from the bottom (this is pulled from a pickled file that *can* be successfully unpickled, but it gives an idea of what I see in the files that can't):

```
(g10
(I0
tp25
g12
tp26
Rp27
(I1
(I2
tp28
g19
I00
Vq=\u000a×£°(@R¸&#x1E;\u2026ëQ.@
p29
tp30
bssb.
```

There is the potential for this to cause an error somewhere in the chain of

1. pickling to a string in IronPython
2. passing that string to a C# object
3. serializing that object with an XmlSerializer
4. unserializing the xml to get back a C# object
5. passing the string that represents the pickled object back to IronPython
6. unpicking the string in IronPython

Exactly where the error occurs, I don't yet know. I have worked around the problem by pickling the IronPython object with `protocol=-1`, which turns the object into a string of binary gibberish that can survive the process.